# Multiple divs centered aligned left sitting next to each other

Tags: positioning, html, centering

I'm trying to get multiple divs sitting next to each other, centered. When the window gets too small to fit all the divs in one row I would like the overflowing divs to bump down to the next row. Preferably aligned left but still centered.

If this isn't possible I'd also be happy to have them just be centered aligned.

An example of how I would like this to function is the large thumbs at the bottom of this page http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/index2.html

The current page I'm having trouble with is here http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/test.html

Here is my current code:

```
<div
    align="center"
    style="
        clear:both;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        width: 100%;
        visibility: show;"> 


    <div style="height:330px;width:330px;float:left;">
        <div style="left:0px;width:330px;">
            <a class="lib" href="#">
                <img         src="http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/library/space/space_lib.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div style="width:300px;left:0px;">
            <p class="ex2" align="left">Made in Photoshop</p>
            <img src="/media/divider.png" width="100%" height="5px" border="0"  style="opacity:0.0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
            <p class="ex3" align="left">Photoshop created space environments made as concept backgrounds for several character drawings</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="height:330px;width:330px;float:left;">
        <div style="left:0px;width:330px;">
            <a class="lib" href="#">
                <img src="http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/library/glow/glow_lib.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div style="width:300px;left:0px;">
            <p class="ex2" align="left">Made in Photoshop</p>
            <img src="/media/divider.png" width="100%" height="5px" border="0"  style="opacity:0.0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
            <p class="ex3" align="left">Photoshop created space environments made as concept backgrounds for several character drawings</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="height:330px;width:330px;float:left;">
        <div style="left:0px;width:330px;">
            <a class="lib" href="#">
                <img    src="http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/library/faces/faces_lib.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div style="width:300px;left:0px;">
            <p class="ex2" align="left">Made in Photoshop</p>
            <img src="/media/divider.png" width="100%" height="5px" border="0" style="opacity:0.0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
            <p class="ex3" align="left">Photoshop created space environments made as concept backgrounds for several character drawings</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="height:330px;width:330px;float:left;">
        <div style="left:0px;width:330px;">
            <a class="lib" href="#">
                <img src="http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/library/color/color_lib.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div style="width:300px;left:0px;">
            <p class="ex2" align="left">Made in Photoshop</p>
            <img src="/media/divider.png" width="100%" height="5px" border="0" style="opacity:0.0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
            <p class="ex3" align="left">Photoshop created space environments made as concept backgrounds for several character drawings</p>
            <img src="/media/divider.png" width="100%" height="5px" border="0" style="opacity:0.0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <img src="/media/divider.png" width="100%" height="52px" border="0" style="opacity:0.0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but you mean something like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="img">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/library/space/space_lib.png" />
            <p>Picture one..</p>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/library/glow/glow_lib.png" />
            <p>Picture two..</p>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/library/faces/faces_lib.png" />
            <p>Picture three..</p>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/library/color/color_lib.png" />
            <p>Picture four..</p>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think?

Check the JSFiddle [here...](http://jsfiddle.net/72qUf/3/)

Comment: This works great as just photos, but I want the text to be under each photo as well, the solution I came up with for that is nesting DIVs in a containing DIV.  The problem I've run into here is the only way I can only get the DIVS to sit next to each other like the photos is by telling them to float left, and what I don't like about this is that when I'm viewing the page on a large screen and it's all four images sitting next to each other they don't stay centered on the page, they move all the way to the left. I want the page to be dynamic, let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand it completely, but my guess is that you want this? http://jsfiddle.net/72qUf/3/

Comment: http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/test3.html  so that's what that looks like, they're centered in a vertical line, I want them centered but next to each other, such as this http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/index2.html  but with the text

Comment: @loriensleafs Don't forget to add `div.img { float: left; }` to your CSS.

Comment: float left does make it a row, but then when the page is on a larger screen in stead of the 4 images staying centered in a row, it's a row but off to the left.

Comment: basically is there a way to replicate what float left does with out using float left because I want them centered.

Comment: alright, I've figured it out, I have to post here because I cant' post it as an answer for 8 hours, this is the answer that was posted deep in the comments of another post http://jsfiddle.net/nR9Mk/1/

basically they use lists, this is able to force the divs to conform to parameters you set for the list, it treats it like it would any other object.  Thanks to everyone who responded, I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out.